# MVC QueryString is an empty collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use a redirection to the requested URL a user wanted to access after the login but somehow the returnUrl is always null. (I did research on that topic for half an hour and didn't find a solution working for me.)

I debugged the Login view of my app and I'm trying to get the ReturnUrl with

```
new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }
```

inside of my `@using()` tag. I saw that the QueryString is an empty collection and I even tried to use it without QueryString or just with `ViewBag.ReturnUrl` but neither the one nor the other worked for me.

The controller has the right parameters and it do redirect via `RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)` but that doesn't matter if the returnUrl is null.

Comment: What is the URL?  If `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` is empty then it seems to follow that there is no `ReturnUrl` value on the query string.

Comment: `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` inside your view page will be empty. its available in controller

Comment: If you use the `FormsAuthentication` and all other pages are secured with Login, then the page requested will be automatically appended to `ReturnUrl` if browse for a page other than Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all your action methods,use this code

```
RedirectToAction("Login", "ControllerName", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath });
```

In your Login action method use

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl){//code}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public ActionResult FirstAction()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SecondAction",
            new { test = Request.Url.ToString() });
    }

    public ActionResult SecondAction()
    {
        return Redirect(Request.QueryString["test"]);
    }
```